# Обработать двойной клик по элементу option для select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-select

`select` выводится с помощью ajax+jquery в блок `div`. Только `select` не выпадающий, указан атрибут `size="20"`, т.е. выводится блок с полосой прокрутки и элементами `option`. Нужно отработать клик по option'ам.

Получается только если непосредственно в `option` указывать `ondblclick`. Но правильнее вроде в скрипте обработчик прикреплять к элементу. А так сделать не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то что-то должно происходить по двойному клику на динамически собираемом селекте, у которого есть атрибут `multiple`.

```
var selectEl = $('select');
selectEl.on('dblclick', 'option', function(){
    #функционал
});
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTKq9).

```js
var selectEl = $('#select_element');
selectEl.on('dblclick', 'option', function() {
  $('#test-output').append('dbl ' + $(this).val() + '<br/>');
});
```

```css
select {
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select_element" name="select_element" multiple size="5">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<div id="test-output">
</div>
```

Comment: Пробовал так. Не работает. Код селекта возвращается из php-скрипта, к которому обращается js-скрипт.

Comment: так работает же в примере, в чем проблема-то ? динамически грузишь ? ну так ставь селектор для on на более родительский элемент http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DTKq9/1/